# Common Scroll Bar on Right side

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have common scroll bar for both left navigation div and right content div like a simple page, but failed to do so ... no matter what i did scrollbar only acts for content div is there any way for them to act on same scrollbar (on right side of page).

`Link to Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEMPax`

Im beginner to css and cant seem to figure this one out. would be glad if someone can help me out.

Thanks and Regards,
Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `overflow:auto;` to the `nav#slide-menu` selector. If I correctly understood what you want!?

Comment: adding overflow:auto; to the nav#slide-menu wont help since i want both left nav div and right content div to scroll together.....

Comment: Than that is just impossible with CSS. There are 2 separate layers and you just can't scroll them in sync. Maybe some js magic will do the trick, but I am afraid that then performance will suffer, especially on low level devices.

Comment: can we use javascript for this?

Comment: Yes you can, but not sure if it is good idea and what code will look like.